# NSFileManager - fileExistsAtPath:?

Tags: nsurl, nsfilemanager

I am trying to understand how to use `NSFileManager`, but I have a file that does exist on my desktop and the NSFileManager method  `fileExistsAtath:` is returning False when I enter the path of that file. Seems I am missing something. Here is the code.

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

//self.pathToRead is /Users/nikita/Desktop/asdf.wav
NSString *readPath = [[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[self.pathToRead stringValue]] absoluteString];

//readPath is file:///Users/nikita/Desktop/asdf.wav
if(![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:readPath])
   NSLog(@"File does not exist!");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change:

```
NSString *readPath = [[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[self.pathToRead stringValue]] absoluteString];
```

To

```
NSString *readPath = [[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[self.pathToRead stringValue]] path];
```